# Apply gift vouchers to the total invoice amount (including taxes & shipping)

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.4, gift-card

I am looking for a way to offer and process gift cards in Magento 2.3.4.

The vouchers should be able to be used to cover the entire shopping cart including all taxes and shipping costs. Is this possible without additional extensions in Magento 2.3.4?

I found out that it is possible to configure Gift Vouchers using Magentos shopping cart rules, but Gift Vouchers with a fixed discount value cannot be applied to the entire shopping cart (products incl. taxes & shipping) without further enhancements.

Comment: You need to select  Apply to Shipping Amount as yes in shopping cart price rule ,so it will be apply on shipping as well.

Comment: @HiteshAgrawal The option is greyed out and is no longer available once I select "Fixed discount amount for entire basket" from the drop-down menu.